# Terraform add aws_api_gateway_integration response json

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws

I need help to configure the post methods as lambda type without proxy and the 200 response type application / json => Empty

This is my Terraform file at aws, I'm new to Terraform, it just lacked this configuration to work if someone can help me.

I'm having an error response in terraform apply

Error creating API Gateway Integration Response: NotFoundException: Invalid Integration identifier specified Error creating API Gateway Deployment: BadRequestException: No integration defined for method

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "basic-dynamodb-table" {
  name           = "stone-test"
  billing_mode   = "PROVISIONED"
  read_capacity  = 20
  write_capacity = 20
  hash_key       = "id"

  attribute {
    name = "id"
    type = "N"
  }

  ttl {
    attribute_name = "TimeToExist"
    enabled        = false
  }

  tags = {
    Name        = "dynamodb-table-1"
    Environment = "dev"
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "lambda_policy" {
  name = "lambda_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.role_for_LDC.id

  policy = file("policy.json")
}


resource "aws_iam_role" "role_for_LDC" {
  name = "myrole"
  
  assume_role_policy = file("assume_role_policy.json")

}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "stone_register2" {
  filename      = "stone_register.zip"
  function_name = "stone_register3"
  role          = aws_iam_role.role_for_LDC.arn
  handler       = "stone_register.lambda_handler"

  # The filebase64sha256() function is available in Terraform 0.11.12 and later
  # For Terraform 0.11.11 and earlier, use the base64sha256() function and the file() function:
  # source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("stone_register.zip"))}"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("stone_register.zip")

  runtime = "python3.6"

  environment {
    variables = {
      DB_TABLE_NAME = "stone-test"
    }
  }
}



resource "aws_lambda_function" "stone_delete2" {
  filename      = "stone_delete.zip"
  function_name = "stone_delete3"
  role          = aws_iam_role.role_for_LDC.arn
  handler       = "stone_delete.lambda_handler"

  # The filebase64sha256() function is available in Terraform 0.11.12 and later
  # For Terraform 0.11.11 and earlier, use the base64sha256() function and the file() function:
  # source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("stone_delete.zip"))}"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("stone_delete.zip")

  runtime = "python3.6"

  environment {
    variables = {
      DB_TABLE_NAME = "stone-test"
    }
  }
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "stone_search2" {
  filename      = "stone_search.zip"
  function_name = "stone_search3"
  role          = aws_iam_role.role_for_LDC.arn
  handler       = "stone_search.lambda_handler"

  # The filebase64sha256() function is available in Terraform 0.11.12 and later
  # For Terraform 0.11.11 and earlier, use the base64sha256() function and the file() function:
  # source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("stone_search.zip"))}"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("stone_search.zip")

  runtime = "python3.6"

  environment {
    variables = {
      DB_TABLE_NAME = "stone-test"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "stone2" {
  filename      = "bot.zip"
  function_name = "stone3"
  role          = aws_iam_role.role_for_LDC.arn
  handler       = "bot.lambda_handler"

  # The filebase64sha256() function is available in Terraform 0.11.12 and later
  # For Terraform 0.11.11 and earlier, use the base64sha256() function and the file() function:
  # source_code_hash = "${base64sha256(file("bot.zip"))}"
  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256("bot.zip")

  runtime = "python3.6"

  environment {
    variables = {
      DB_TABLE_NAME = "stone-test"
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "apiLambda" {
  name        = "myAPI"

}


  resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "Resource" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "bot"

}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "Method" {
   rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource.id
   http_method   = "POST"
   authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambdaInt" {
   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource.id
   http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.Method.http_method

   integration_http_method = "POST"
   type                    = "AWS"
   uri                     = aws_lambda_function.stone2.invoke_arn
   
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.Method.http_method
  status_code = "200"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "MyDemoIntegrationResponse" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.Method.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.response_200.status_code
}

  resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "Resource2" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "register"

}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "Method2" {
   rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource2.id
   http_method   = "POST"
   authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambdaInt2" {
   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource2.id
   http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.Method2.http_method

   integration_http_method = "POST"
   type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
   uri                     = aws_lambda_function.stone_register2.invoke_arn
   
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "Resource3" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "delete"

}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "Method3" {
   rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource3.id
   http_method   = "POST"
   authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambdaInt3" {
   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource3.id
   http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.Method3.http_method

   integration_http_method = "POST"
   type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
   uri                     = aws_lambda_function.stone_delete2.invoke_arn
   
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "Resource4" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "search"

}

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "Method4" {
   rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource4.id
   http_method   = "POST"
   authorization = "NONE"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "lambdaInt4" {
   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.Resource4.id
   http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.Method4.http_method

   integration_http_method = "POST"
   type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
   uri                     = aws_lambda_function.stone_search2.invoke_arn
   
}


resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "apideploy" {
   depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_integration.lambdaInt]

   rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.id
   stage_name  = "Prod"
}


resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw" {
   statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
   action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
   function_name = aws_lambda_function.stone2.function_name
   principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

   source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.execution_arn}/Prod/POST/bot"

}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw2" {
   statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
   action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
   function_name = aws_lambda_function.stone_register2.function_name
   principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

   source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.execution_arn}/Prod/POST/register"

}

  


resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw3" {
   statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
   action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
   function_name = aws_lambda_function.stone_delete2.function_name
   principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

   source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.execution_arn}/Prod/POST/delete"

}


resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw4" {
   statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway"
   action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
   function_name = aws_lambda_function.stone_search2.function_name
   principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"

   source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apiLambda.execution_arn}/Prod/POST/search"

}

 


output "base_url" {
  value = aws_api_gateway_deployment.apideploy.invoke_url
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already on the correct path, all you need to do create the [method_response](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_method_response)  and use the same for creating the [integration_response](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_integration_response)

And change the [integration type](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_integration)

There is a comprehensive list of the types and what they can do and how can you leverage them in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-api-integration-types.html)

I only adjusted a few settings in the code you shared, which are below:

```
...
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS"
  uri = aws_lambda_function.lambda.invoke_arn
}

....

resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "response_200" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method
  status_code = "200"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "MyDemoIntegrationResponse" {
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.resource.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.method.http_method
  status_code = aws_api_gateway_method_response.response_200.status_code
}
```

when I test the function from the AWS console I get the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much I tried but I had the following error as an answer

My code: https://pastebin.com/tqssNVxt

Error creating API Gateway Integration Response: NotFoundException: Invalid Integration identifier specified

Error creating API Gateway Deployment: BadRequestException: No integration defined for method

Comment: you can tell me where I went wrong, I edited my question.  My code https://pastebin.com/tqssNVxt

Comment: seems like a race condition, can you place a [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/meta-arguments/depends_on.html) clause for < aws_api_gateway_integration> .

Comment: @AdilmarCoelhoDantas if this works for you can accept this as an answer, this helps the community and anyone who stumble upon this qeustion.